# list index out of range while data scraping

Tags: python, indexing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to scrape user data from a website. I am using the following code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
a=0
pattern = regex.compile(r"UID_(\w+)\-SRC_\d+")
for user in soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"memberOverlayLink"}):
        id = soup.find_all("div",id=pattern)[a]["id"]
        uid=pattern.match(id).group(1)
        print(uid)
        a=a+1
```

After getting the first 10 rsults I am getting this result

```
623946C8E24FB61D64DC19129ED61306
82E2983AA905CACB8CABF565BDDC1BFF
97598DF4333C7D9C430F29D02CF35304
FF9B4B5BB920DE1274286D57043221C7
E61CB7A638FA90F9A714BD0A70D5E730
6CD8A7AEFC3786FB7B353DCDD2A0BF48
4A0C7A5F824ED470C149A032D23DCA28
FB9F5FA7A0F1FD2B647F319B807A6072
088E6A96810B1B797F4BFE8386289BFD
60CE07D6DF5C02A987ED7B076F4154F3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Utkarsh/Brookfield/TripAdvisorPython-master/New_Scrapetest.py",    line 9, in <module>
id = soup.find_all("div", id=pattern)[a]["id"]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I noticed that their is only data of 10 users on the first page. But I am not able to figure out what break condition I should use or how handle this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
a=0
pattern = regex.compile(r"UID_(\w+)\-SRC_\d+")
for user in soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"memberOverlayLink"}):
        try:
            id = soup.find_all("div",id=pattern)[a]["id"]
            uid=pattern.match(id).group(1)
            print(uid)
            a=a+1
        except IndexError:
            break
```

I am basically using a `try/except` block for this. You can read more about it on https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Happy to help. Also please mark this as accepted so that it can help other fellow developers.